# achartengine; fitting all x axis labels without clipping, and without margins on graph

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm using a fill to color the area below my chart, and I want the graph to take up the entire view, so I'm setting zero margin on the right and left in my renderer.

```
mRenderer.setMargins(new int[]{20, 0, 20, 0});
```

Graph renders great; uses all horizontal space and doesn't look wonky like it does without fill extending to right or left margins when they're set to > 0 values.

I'm also using custom text labels, aligned center, and I'm getting the outer two labels clipped; setting padding on x labels amplifies the problem by pushing labels off view.

Is there a way I can fit all the x labels in without the truncation, and without having to use margins? I can fit them all using margins, but then it just looks funky using the fill below.

Ideally, I guess there'd be some way to set alignment on each text label individually; probably asking for a lot. Or, a means to specify whether it should fit x labels when using custom text labels, such that it would align right on the first, and align left on the last.

Thanks

Comment: Can u show some snaps what happening and what u want ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I resorted to using margins to make sure all the labels fit. I was trying to have the chart container to match parent horizontally, so the graph would occupy the entire horizontal space. But doing that, it's impossible to get the x axis labels completely in the view. When centered, both the first and last labels are clipped somewhat. I also tried adding dummy, blank labels on each end, but that resulted in the graph looking very "silo-ish", as there's no real values corresponding to either end point.

Comment: well, I'm ok as it's going to be; I used margins, so the graph has edges on either side, but it's more important to have the labels. So yes, I'm ok ;-)